# Can I mix & match different chainring brand/model?

Tags: mountain-bike, chainring

I want to change my 36 Race Face Evolve chainring (in a 22/36 setup) for a 32t. I've found a "cheap" Race Face Turbine 32t. Will it be compatibile with the 22t "Evolve" chainring or I will get shifting problems?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Leo.

Answer (score 3):

Should be fine, if the new 32t ring is made to be used in a double or triple crankset then your gold. If it is made to be run independently in a 1x drivetrain (Such as a narrow/wide ring) then it will cause shifting issues.

The larger of the two (or three) rings has shifting ramps and/or pins that help guide the chain up during shifting. If it is made to be used in a multiple ring setup then these should be present, generally they rings will list what type of setup they are intended for as well such as 1x , 2x or 3x.

The other thing to check to to be sure the bolt pattern (BCD) is the same so that they will bolt together. You may also consider getting a new chain at the same time if it has been awhile.

Comment: so I could even mix & match from different manufacturers, as long as the rings are not meant for a 1x drivetrain and if the BCD is the right one??? So I could have a Shimano 32t with a Race Face 22t?

Comment: Most likely yes, one thing to consider is that not all teeth are the same, they are very similar but different manufacturers use different tolerances and such. So between brands you may get some shifting issues, but often times they will work just fine. One other thing to consider is that you may have to resize your chain a link or two as you are losing 6 teeth worth of size.